# Swiper pagination not showing

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

First time using swiper ,I followed the documentation and added the html part in my code ,then initialize it in JS, I initialize pagination but it is not showing on my page. This is my code:

JS:

```
var Swiper = require('swiper');
   $(document).ready(() => {
      var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
        }
      });
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
   </div>
```

can someone explain me what am I doing wrong I get the pagination element height and width in px ?

Comment: what's the error ?

Answer (score 56):

Post is old, but still don't have correct answer, so:

You need to import modules.

```
// core version + navigation, pagination modules:
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

// configure Swiper to use modules
Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

// init Swiper:
const swiper = new Swiper(...);
```

Docs: https://swiperjs.com/get-started/

Comment: or directly in the constructor:
`const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  modules: [Navigation, Pagination]
});`

Answer (score 4):

if you are not using it with webpack and and transpiler then you cannot use require.
you will have to use the cdn or you can download the scripts and use them.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For React, you need to import the bundled css file.

```
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add clickable value.

`pagination: { el: '.swiper-pagination', clickable: true }`

Answer (score 1):

import "swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss";

put this it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If importing Pagination and Navigation does not fix the issue for you, like mentioned above. Make sure you also have an empty `div` tag with the class `swiper-pagination`.

Like so:

```
<div class="rewards-swiper">
  <div class={swiperClass} ref={el => this.swiperRef = el}>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <slot />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination" />    <-- here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.scss' instead of this 'swiper/css/pagination'

for some reason you dont download the css module even when you install the same version.

but this works!!